# Menu expand on page reload

Tags: php, browser, compatibility

I am facing a problem that when i reload my page all the child menu are expand and after reload they are all well.why child menu are expand.
my site link is
[www.thesouq.com](http://www.thesouq.com/index.php)

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: load common.css first, you need to optimize your page, there are to many http request, use Yslow to check the areas you can improve

Answer (score 0):

Try putting js file of menu right after jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.menu.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.menu.hover.js"></script>
```

try removing this block also

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
       include ("scripts/jquery.menu.js");
    }
</script>
```

I have check it using firebug you menu call is very late since doc is not ready.

Please optimize your page, check out Yslow, it will help you a lot

Comment: thanks Saqueib for help.but i am facing the problem.plz help me.